# Generated URLs don't reflect accurate URLs.

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomains, domain-mapping

Evening,

I'm getting some incorrect links generated by my theme.

`WordPress Address (URL): http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress`

`Site Address (URL): http://localhost/newgameplus`

Clicking on something like `preview post` 
Generates a URL like this:

`http://localhost/newgameplus/?p=34`

The correct URL is: 
`http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress/?p=34`

How can I make it reflect this?

(Also, I cannot change site Address because my site is in a different subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Site Address (URL)**
>   Enter the address you want people to type in their
>   browser to reach your WordPress site. This is the directory where
>   WordPress's main index.php file is installed. The Site address (URL)
>   is identical to the WordPress address (URL) (above) unless you are
>   giving WordPress its own directory. WordPress will trim a slash (/)
>   from the end. If you defined the WP_HOME constant in your
>   wp-config.php file, that value will appear in this field and you will
>   not be able to make changes to it from the WordPress administration
>   screen.

1. Either change Site Address (URL) to: `http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress`
2. Or copy index.php into localhost/newgameplus and change `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` to `require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: 1.  I cannot change the site address, else my cookies get messed up.  I encounter an issue where users are not able to log in. 
(Wordpress is installed in a folder called /wordpress/ under the root directory)

2.  Which index.php do I copy?  There are lots, and the one for my theme has no require.  I'm using toolbox.

Comment: @Adola You change the index.php in the root directory.

Comment: Great deal!  

All works as expected!